# Is it possible and reasonable to convince JSHint to accept a single line `do` loop?

Tags: jshint

This is clear (IMO) and valid javascript:

```
do var playerId = newPlayerId();
while(playerId in players);
```

JSHint complains that it expected a `{` before `playerId`. Is there any way to disable this warning, without disabling all curly-brace related warnings? My style is cool, right? No ambiguities or obscurities?

Comment: You can add in the braces and still have it be a one liner.

Comment: JSHint does what it says. It gives you a 'hint' for potentially invalid javascript. It's still up to you to decide what to do. What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: I am using Syntastic for vim, and these hints are big and red and hard to ignore. I think curly braces are easier on the eyes than the warning, but maybe it was a mistake to integrate JSHint with the editor, if it leads to slightly less readable code. On the other hand, JSHint has caught lots of little mistakes of mine... decisions, decisions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, this does not appear to be possible. It is possible with other similar statements (such as `if` and `while`) by setting the `curly` option to `false`:

```
/*jshint curly: false */
var x = 10;
if (x < 20)
    x = 30;
```

I see no reason why this rule should not apply to the `do` statement, so I've [opened a pull request](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/pull/1062) to add this functionality to JSHint.